# Accessing data from the callback function of a bar chart using chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am currently trying to show a text stocked in the data in the tooltip, I can#t figure how to make it work, I have tried many things.

You can find below an example of what I#m trying to do, I want that the "text" value is displayed when hovering one of the bar.

I tried this

```
let data = [{
      label: 'Available',
      backgroundColor: '#3366ff',
      data: [500],
      text : "test1"
    }, {
      label: 'Budget',
      backgroundColor: '#009999',
      data: [5000, 6500],
      text : "test2"
    }, {
      label: 'Actual',
      backgroundColor: '#92d400',
      data: [5200, 7245],
      text : "test3"
    }];

    new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart-horizontal"), {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: {
            labels: ["Rooms", "Guests"],
            datasets: data,
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            },
            tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                        var item = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                        return item.text;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

But this is not working, it is not even displaying anything logical, only "Room" and "Guests".

What should I do to retrieve the correct informations ? I tried doing it like this : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ks5hwLo/)

But it doesn't work when applied to my code... I'm probably missing something pretty stupid but I can't figure what.

Thanks to all the people that will read this and try to help me.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
...
options: {
  tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      label: (context, data)  => data.datasets[context.datasetIndex].data[context.index].text
    }
  }
...
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfszb07t/8/)

Comment: What I wanted is not to just display the values but what is in the text, so for example when passing over my first bar I want it to display "test1" too.
And sorry I just realised that I sent the wrong fiddle, this is the correct one : https://jsfiddle.net/8ks5hwLo/
This is with line but I want to do the same with bar

Comment: @Kura check the updated answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update the version of chart.js you are using to the latest V2 version since V3 has breaking changes.

Also you need to specify the x for the number for a horizontalBar instead of a y in both the dataset and the tooltip callback:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: ['2017/06/12', '2017/06/23', '2017/07/12', '2017/07/23', '2017/08/12', '2017/08/23', '2017/09/12'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Values',
      data: [{
          x: 12,
          value: 12,
          text: "test1"
        },
        {
          x: 3,
          value: 13,
          text: "test2"
        },
        {
          x: 1,
          value: 15,
          text: "test3"
        },
        {
          x: -3,
          value: 5,
          text: "test4"
        },
        {
          x: 67,
          value: 18,
          text: "test5"
        },
        {
          x: 12,
          value: 11,
          text: "test6"
        },
        {
          x: 13,
          value: 19,
          text: "test7"
        }
      ],
      fill: false,
      borderWidth: 2
    }]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var item = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
          return item.x + ' ' + item.value + item.text;
        }
      }
    },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```